# is there any options to change bundle identifier while generating the build using terminal

Tags: xcode, terminal, xcode-command-line-tools

i) is it possible to change the Bundle identifier and Provisional Profiles in Codebase while generating the Archive File and IPA file.

ii) is it possible to change the Application name while generating IPA file in Command line Tools.

```
I am following these two syntax while generating the Archive and IPA.


xcodebuild -workspace ".workspace" -scheme "SchemeName"  -archivePath "archivePath/appName.xcarchive" archive

xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath "archivePath/appName.xcarchive" \
  -exportOptionsPlist "ecportOptionsPlist" \
   -exportPath "ExportPath"
```